# What's a good control to use for re/drawing large graphic contents in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, 2d, picturebox

I'm creating a basic level editor for a game which is tile based, so I'm looking for a good/optimal way of drawing a bunch of tiles which equal a typical screen resolution at minimum (~1080p); in a way that allows me to redraw things quickly when necessary (including an overlaying grid).

I have been trying to make it work using a PictureBox control by drawing in the OnPaint event. I thought this might be a good idea at first, until I realized how slow redrawing became when I added a simple grid drawing algorithm - it was taking a few seconds to complete redraws at high resolutions (<1080p still, though).

I can't see this solution scaling very well to allow me to create a latency free editor. Does anybody have any suggestions for a component or method of making this kind of semi-intense graphics drawing/redrawing possible?

*Note: Ideally I would like to use a control that can be placed in a panel whereby the autoscroll of the panel works for panning around the control if it should be too large.*

**Drawing code**:

```
public void DrawLevel(Graphics graphics, Rectangle viewport)
{
    SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.DarkGray);
    graphics.FillRectangle(b, 0, 0, viewport.Width, viewport.Height);
}

public void DrawGrid(Graphics graphics, Rectangle viewport)
{
    Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
    for (int x = 0; x < viewport.Width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < viewport.Height; y++)
        {
            if (x == 0 || (x % 32) == 0)
                graphics.DrawLine(p, x, 0, x, viewport.Height - 1);
            if (y == 0 || (y % 32) == 0)
                graphics.DrawLine(p, 0, y, viewport.Width - 1, y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "it was taking a few seconds to complete redraws at high resolutions" - seems far too slow. suspect your algorithm....post your code

Comment: drawing code edited in - i already know drawing the grid could be faster by incrementing x and y by 32, instead of using modulo, but i don't think it can be _that_ different at this scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use OpenTK with a GLControl.

Comment: I wholeheartly agree. Do not use windows forms if you want to create a game of any kind. It is not a pit of success. Your will not be able to build any kind of advanced scenes. You will need to re-learn a new rendering framework as soon as you do anything but the most basic.

Comment: yep, GLControl is exactly the kind of thing i was looking for. thank you~

Answer (score 3):

This code is strange with O(viewport.Width * viewport.Height)

```
for (int x = 0; x < viewport.Width; x++) 
{ 
    for (int y = 0; y < viewport.Height; y++) 
    { 
        if (x == 0 || (x % 32) == 0) 
            graphics.DrawLine(p, x, 0, x, viewport.Height - 1); 
        if (y == 0 || (y % 32) == 0) 
            graphics.DrawLine(p, 0, y, viewport.Width - 1, y); 
    } 
}
```

Use next code with O((viewport.Width + viewport.Height)/32)

```
for (int x = 0; x < viewport.Width; x+=32) 
{ 
   graphics.DrawLine(p, x, 0, x, viewport.Height - 1); 
}
for (int y = 0; y < viewport.Height; y+=32) 
{ 
   graphics.DrawLine(p, 0, y, viewport.Width - 1, y); 
}
```